# Sonta Admin Bundle List Url Customization

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I want to pass a parameter value to the route with the content of the current cell.

```
$listMapper->add("parent_id", 'url', array(
    'route' => array(
        'name'=>'admin_xxxxx_news_news_show', 
        'absolute'=>true, 
        'identifier_parameter_name'=>"parentID"
    )
);
```

I have a route `admin_xxxxx_news_news_show` and have to pass the parameter from the current column. I don't have a relation of the current field with the related entity. I am using two columns for association, one for the entity and second for that entity ID. With my current knowledge of Symfony2 I need to have a customized view.